# The extraction of coq type nat into which type of ocaml so that I can have a certified program

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

In `Coq`, the extraction from type `nat` into `int` or `big_int` are not certified (they are efficient). As in these links below:

http://coq.inria.fr/V8.3/stdlib/Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlNatBigInt.html
and

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/8.3/stdlib/Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlNatInt.html

Both saying that:
*Disclaimer: trying to obtain efficient certified programs by extracting nat into big_int isn't necessarily a good idea. See comments in ExtrOcamlNatInt.v.*

If I have `coq` types:`nat`,`Z, N`, and `positive` which `ocaml` types should I choose to get the type extracted that I can have a certified (safer) program (I can ignore the efficient)?.

Currently, I chose to extract all of them into `int`. And then inside `ocaml int` I used the `Int64` to hack inside (get the boundary `min_int` and `max_int`, if `k < min_int` then `min_int`, and otherwise), for `Z` and `positive` number I check that: if `(i:int) < 0` then return type non-negative int, if `i <= 0` then it is of type `positive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about efficiency, you should not try to bind Coq's type to Ocaml ones, just extract them as they are (inductive types) and you will be safe. However using computation over `nat` (unary numbers) will be really slow. For example:

```
Extraction nat.
(*
  type nat =
   | O
   | S of nat
 *)
```

Extracting `Z` will be a bit more verbose.

Comment: In my program, I need to bind it to ocaml ones. If I have to use the ocaml types, which type is safer in this case (is it big_int because I need to deal with a big integers?). Thanks.

Comment: I really don't know, sorry. What do you mean by "safer" ?

Comment: `big_int` is safer than `int` because `nat`, `positive`, `N`, and `Z` can get arbitrarily large, and `Z` can also get arbitrarily small. With large numbers, `int` would just wrap around or get capped, so your proofs wouldn't be valid. Mapping Coq numbers to Ocaml numbers doesn't require special care, but mapping operations does. For example, `Extract Constant pred => "fun n -> Big.max Big.zero (Big.pred n)"`.